# How to add maps to one simulator?

Tags: simulation, dtn, one-simulator

I am using one simulator and wanted to add my own maps. So I looked into this website https://mygeodata.cloud/ which can provide me with the `wkt` files of maps.

The problem is I am not able to get these to work, can someone provide some details on how to add a town's map with maybe bus routes etc to `ONE Simulator`?

The error I'm getting is **"SimMap is not fully connected. Only 1057 out of 1113 map nodes can be reached from Nt2@(-1.15,52.95). E.g. Nt2@(-1.14,52.95) can't be reached"**

The default roads.wtk files have linestrings like this

> ```
> LINESTRING (2551683.6644129306 6674375.029443317, 2551528.069902012
> 6674337.650863852)
> ```

While my linestrings of Nottingham,England are this

> ```
> LINESTRING (-1.1525824 52.9518235,-1.1524917 52.9517354,-1.1519975 > 
> 52.9511418,-1.1517313 52.9508255)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your input map has around 50 nodes that can not be reached from other map nodes. The ONE Simulator needs to have the map fully connected (i.e., all nodes need to be reachable). Check out the map source (e.g., using [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/)) and look for nodes or map segments that are not connected to each other and delete them or connect them with new  line segments. The error message gives you a hint where to look at.

For an example on how to add bus routes, check out the Helsinki map and the tram/bus route files: https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/tree/master/data

Answer (score 0):

that is because there is a broken node there should be a check again for the existing map input because some moves do not want any broken lines there can make messages from open strapmaps then edit using open jump